# Error when trying to Promisify JWT in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt

I am trying to promisify jwt verify in typescript, but I am getting this error.

"Expected 1 argument, but got 2.ts(2554)"

Sync version is working fine.

How to fix it?

```
import util from 'util';
const promisify = util.promisify;

const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string);
console.log(decoded);
```

Comment: Did you look at the type of `promisify(jwt.verify)`?

Comment: Types of verify function 

function verify(token: string, secretOrPublicKey: jwt.Secret, options: jwt.VerifyOptions & {
    complete: true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glancing at the [types for jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/912781723258c5d318b1b8349a5b85e834b7eaf9/types/jsonwebtoken/index.d.ts#L103) and the [documentation for verify](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) that *should* have worked. But we don't live in a perfect world. You can always promisify the function yourself:

```
const jwtVerifyPromisified = (token, secret) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, payload) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(payload);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

You'll have to add some annotations but you get the idea.